# SQL query exploring a graph with multiple parents

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, parent-child, hierarchy

I need to explore a table which describes a graph, but the complexity is due to the fact that each node can have a parent of a different type, so the hierarchy is not simply done across a parent column and a child column

**DEMO STRUCTURE AND DATA**

```
If object_id('dbo.TST_COMPONENT') is not null
DROP table TST_COMPONENT

CREATE TABLE TST_COMPONENT (
    [MAT_CODE] VARCHAR(max)
    , [SPEC_CODE] VARCHAR(max)
    , [COMP_MAT_CODE] VARCHAR(max)
    , [COMP_SPEC_CODE] VARCHAR(max)
    );

INSERT INTO TST_COMPONENT (
    [MAT_CODE], [SPEC_CODE], [COMP_MAT_CODE], [COMP_SPEC_CODE]
    )
VALUES
    ('M1', NULL, 'M2', NULL),
    ('M1', NULL, 'M4', NULL),
    ('M2', NULL, NULL, 'S3'),
    ('M2', NULL, 'M6', NULL),
    (NULL, 'S3', 'M5', NULL),
    ('M4', NULL, NULL, 'S4'),
    ('M5', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('M6', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    (NULL, 'S4', NULL, 'S5'),
    (NULL, 'S5', 'M7', NULL),
    ('M7', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

In this case M1 has M2 and M4 as children, M2 has M6 and S3, while S3 has M5. On the other branch, M4 goes to S4 then S6 and finally M7.

Which is the fastest way to explore this tree with a SQL query? Even better is it works for Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean by "explore"?  What results do you want?  *(Also, the data structure appears to be painful and likely inappropriate, are you able to change that if we can suggest something more appropriate?)*

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using?  Please provide expected results and a description of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Also, please explain the rules that makes `m1` the parent of `m2` and `m4`, and the rules that make `s3` the parent of `m5`. (I have my own guess, but this is not something I should need to guess - it should be expressed clearly in your question).

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve something like this

```
WITH MyCTE
AS ( SELECT MAT_CODE, SPEC_CODE, COMP_MAT_CODE, COMP_SPEC_CODE
FROM TST_COMPONENT
WHERE MAT_CODE = 'M1'
UNION ALL
SELECT C.MAT_CODE, C.SPEC_CODE, C.COMP_MAT_CODE, C.COMP_SPEC_CODE
FROM TST_COMPONENT C
    INNER JOIN MyCTE ON
    (
        ( C.MAT_CODE = MyCTE.COMP_MAT_CODE AND C.SPEC_CODE IS NULL)
        OR
        ( C.SPEC_CODE = MyCTE.COMP_SPEC_CODE AND C.MAT_CODE IS NULL)
    )
    --WHERE C.MAT_CODE = MyCTE.COMP_MAT_CODE AND C.SPEC_CODE = MyCTE.COMP_SPEC_CODE
)
SELECT * FROM MyCTE
```

It seems like it covers my requirement, only I am not sure if it is the best and if it actually is covering all possible cases.

Comment: Looks OK. In [Oracle solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfa304/1) a list of column aliases for CTE is required.

Comment: So, you just want a query that returns a specified node and all its descendants?  But that returned data set does not need to include any additional information, such as the path from the specified node, the depth or relative depth, etc?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to get note and all descendants. It would be nice to have the path to a specific node indeed, I didn't think about it in my initial post.